# MySQL error on form submission

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a mysql error saying "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near..."

Here's the basics of my code:

First I'm populating the select menu options with rows from the categories table.  This is working fine:

```
 <select id="dropdown-select" name="Name">
<option value="" id="dropdown-option">Please select a category.</option>
<?php
    $query_categories = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    $result_categories = mysql_query($query_categories) or die(mysql_error());

    while($categories_row = mysql_fetch_array($result_categories)) {
        echo '<option id="dropdown-option" value="' . $categories_row['cat_name'] . '">' . $categories_row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Later, when I go submit the form to the transactions table (the above table I pulled data from was the categories table, could this be a problem?) is when I get the error.  I think its related to the above code bc if I remove this element from my form submission, it writes the rest of the values to the database without any errors.

```
 if(!isset($_POST['Name'])) {
    die('You must select an income or expense from the drop down menu.');
} else {
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
}
 //create query
$query = "INSERT INTO transaction (month, trans_name, budgeted, actual) VALUES ('$Month', '$Name', $Budgeted', '$Actual')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a single quote in your insert statement before $Budgeted

```
INSERT INTO transaction (month, trans_name, budgeted, actual) VALUES ('$Month', '$Name', '$Budgeted', '$Actual')"
```

Comment: wow.  I'm an idiot.  I'm sorry to waste everyone's time. Sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have some fields which are defined in Database as `VARCHAR`, `CHAR`.

Also, if you are inserting a string value in Database from a PHP script, you need to add an enclosing single quote (`'`) around it.

In your case, you are inserting a string without `semicolons`, so, it showing error in MySQL.

Your statement should be corrected by adding a single quote around `$budget` as:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO transaction (month, trans_name, budgeted, actual) VALUES ('$Month',
 '$Name', '$Budgeted', '$Actual')";
    ------^
```

Answer (score 1):

The error "You have an error in your SQL syntax" is exactly correct!

```
$query = "INSERT INTO transaction (month, trans_name, budgeted, actual) 
          VALUES ('$Month', '$Name', $Budgeted', '$Actual')";
Look here, you missed something ----^
```

There is a `'` missing from your statement causing the syntax error. Put the single quote in and you should be good to go!